# jQuery fadeIn effect not working its Flicker which apply on 2 divs, but show/hide works perfect need to change bg image with fading effect

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yUKdh/4/)**

I have 4 bg images and want to change the background img when ever mouse enter over menus .ie. (flying stars in my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yUKdh/4/)) and on mouseout it will show default background image.

- On **menuone &  on star1**    -  `background image one display`
- On **menutwo &  on star2**   -  `background image two display`
- On **menuthree &  on star3**  -  `background image three display`

like wise on mouse out default image will show.
i have done with hide,show its works, but when i try fadein effect it look different, i need fade effect while changing bg images

Please have a look at `menuShowDisplaywithFadeEffect()` function

**code:**

```
function menuShowDisplaywithFadeEffect() {
    $("#star1").on("mouseover", function () {
        //$("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);  
        $("#OneDiv").show();
        $("#Tab1Btn").show();
      });
   $("#star1").on("mouseout", function () {
        $("#OneDiv").hide();
        $("#Tab1Btn").hide();
      });
   $("#Tab1Btn").on("mouseover", function () {
        $("#OneDiv").show();
        $("#Tab1Btn").show();
      });
   $("#Tab1Btn").on("mouseout", function () {
        $("#OneDiv").hide();
        $("#Tab1Btn").hide();
      });
    // same for others menus ....
  }
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="defaultDiv">
    <img class="style5" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/a4IA9ozfybUYvvwmCEUqI49ymubwfULp6rs-EPJXtqM=w284-h203-p-no" /></div>
<div id="OneDiv">
    <img class="style5" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/lznxp8Ak4UuSLXPICUM8Tz0-BloSkMQMO5JDNKFE3BQ=w289-h207-p-no" /></div>
<div id="twoDiv">
    <img class="style5" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/0EK7Ksqb1S5jXhal-yMf85KUymYBVNbgLY36ORjMag0=w289-h207-p-no" /></div>
<div id="threeDiv">
    <img class="style5" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/CJgDQ9889e25EqfSEv-SbjwBJ41AJluJkQBHM8Ixq_o=w289-h207-p-no" /></div>
<div id="menudiv">
    <div id="star1" class="clsstar addData">
        <div class="startab"></div></div>
    <div id="Tab1Btn" class="addData"><a href="#">Menu one</a> </div>

   <div id="star2" class="clsstar addData2">
        <div class="startab"></div></div>
    <div id="Tab2Btn" class="addData2"><a href="#">Menu two</a></div>

   <div id="star3" class="clsstar addData3">
        <div class="startab"></div>  </div>
    <div id="Tab3Btn" class="addData3"><a href="#">Menu three</a></div>
</div>
```

**Edited:**

I tried  to stop animation .i.e moving stars on mouse hover and restart on out, but it only works 1st time, still not able to fix my issue

```
jQuery("#star1").hover(function () {
    clearInterval(resultAnimation);
    jQuery("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);
    jQuery("#OneDiv").show();
    jQuery("#Tab1Btn").show();
},
function () {
    resultAnimation = setInterval(myFunctionRotation, 100);
    jQuery("#OneDiv").fadeOut(400);
    jQuery("#Tab1Btn").hide();
});
```

Comment: `fadeIn` seems to work fine if I uncomment the commented parts of your code.

Comment: @Harry: which part you have uncommented pls provide updated link

Comment: Sorry, I had closed the fiddle. But I just changed `//$("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);` to `$("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);`

Comment: @Harry: yeah i tried it earlier, nut by doing this it create flicker when i move mouse over respected menus

Comment: sorry mate, I just don't seem to understand your issue :( but looks like SilverBlade has.

Answer (score 1):

**Change all .show to .fadeIn(400) and .hide to .fadeOut(400) :**

```
function menuShowDisplaywithFadeEffect() {
    $("#star1").on("mouseover", function () {
        //$("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);  
        $("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);
        $("#Tab1Btn").fadeIn(400);
    });

    $("#star1").on("mouseout", function () {

        $("#OneDiv").fadeOut(400);
        $("#Tab1Btn").fadeOut(400);
    });

    $("#star2").on("mouseover", function () {
        //  $("#twoDiv").fadeIn(400);  
        $("#twoDiv").fadeIn(400);
        $("#Tab2Btn").fadeIn(400);
    });

    $("#star2").on("mouseout", function () {
        $("#twoDiv").fadeOut(400);
        $("#Tab2Btn").fadeOut(400);
    });

    $("#star3").on("mouseover", function () {
        //   $("#threeDiv").fadeIn(400);  
        $("#threeDiv").fadeIn(400);
        $("#Tab3Btn").fadeIn(400);
    });

    $("#star3").on("mouseout", function () {

        $("#threeDiv").fadeOut(400);
        $("#Tab3Btn").fadeOut(400);
    });

    $("#Tab1Btn").on("mouseover", function () {
        $("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);
        $("#Tab1Btn").fadeIn(400);
    });

    $("#Tab1Btn").on("mouseout", function () {
        $("#OneDiv").fadeOut(400);
        $("#Tab1Btn").fadeOut(400);
    });

    $("#Tab2Btn").on("mouseover", function () {
        $("#twoDiv").fadeIn(400);
        $("#Tab2Btn").fadeIn(400);
    });

    $("#Tab2Btn").on("mouseout", function () {
        $("#twoDiv").fadeOut(400);
        $("#Tab2Btn").fadeOut(400);
    });

    $("#Tab3Btn").on("mouseover", function () {
        $("#threeDiv").fadeIn(400);
        $("#Tab3Btn").fadeIn(400);
    });

    $("#Tab3Btn").on("mouseout", function () {
        $("#threeDiv").fadeOut(400);
        $("#Tab3Btn").fadeOut(400);
    });

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
$("#OneDiv").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400);
$("#Tab1Btn").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: @markvicencio- by doing this it gives flicker effect, one mouse over menus, just check demo http://jsfiddle.net/yUKdh/9/

Comment: what are you really trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to change background image with fadeing effect, on each menu represnet different images, and when mouse position is none of the menus, it has to display default images with fading effect, menus as well as stars

Comment: I just noticed the circles are moving right? Maybe it is the reason why its flickering.

Comment: yeah may be thats the reason, but still trying to sloved it

Comment: Try adding this $("#OneDiv").stop(true, true).fadeIn(400); See my edit

Comment: i tried it still not fix my issue, when mouse over menu text and star1 its flicker , http://jsfiddle.net/yUKdh/13/

Comment: @Satindersingh You are hiding your menu items when you hover, right? So the hover function deactivates since your menu item is gone. Then it appears again and this can cause the flickering

Comment: of course you need to apply it in all fadeIn and fadeOut effects

Comment: Another thing! The Star (WHICH is the circle) has his own size and the text Menu has his width and height own also. That's why it gives you flickering effect because your hovering two different things

Comment: @DarkAshelin: yes menutext will display only when mouse over at respected **star** and hide when mouse out

Comment: @markvicencio: yes i agree with you text menu and stars are different size , for that i gave smae class to them and like this http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: I think the best solution maybe when you hovered the stars, stop the animation that gives that star movement and then when you hovered out then animate it again.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing two div, but making fadeIn effect uopn a single one.

You need to apply the effect to both,

```
    $("#OneDiv").fadeIn(400);  
    $("#Tab1Btn").fadeIn(400);
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yUKdh/7/

Note: Just applied the effect to mouse events of the start#

Comment: thanks for reply, but its still not working you can see on tab1btn its flickers, and also on mouseout default image shows without fade effect

Comment: Yes, as you are making the tab to move, so its losing the mouseover effect and gains mouseout effect. You could do as such that when the tab is hovered then no movement will be there so it will stop the flickering issue.

Comment: @SilverBlade- that moving start effect will be there i cant change it, but i can change html markup , still struggling with that,

Comment: @Satindersingh Sorry you misunderstood me. If you can make the stars not move when the mouse is over it and then again start the animation once the mouse loses the focus from it. It will surely make the fadeIn animation stable.

Comment: its sound great by hearing, have to try this, do you have idea how to stop on mouse hover

Comment: yeah thanks for trying am waiting for reply, meantime am also trying it